# How to avoid being recognized by ReCAPTCHA V2?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, bots, undetected-chromedriver

I've been doing some form-entry-stuffing tests in a buddy's website with Selenium by filling a form automatically. The form has a ReCaptcha box at the bottom which will give us nightmares for weeks. Basically, the first couple of entries I get in work perfectly (every instance of Selenium is run with a different proxy). But the more entries I submit, the harder the Captcha becomes until it'll take me 1 minute to solve a single one. I've tried many things without success.

At first the Captchas would be long straight off the bat, since I had the webdriver flag on. I managed to patch Chromedriver so ReCAPTCHA won't recognize me as a bot. Later on I disabled webrtc which seemed to help in being less conspicuous, and was getting shorter challenges, sometimes even one challenge and done.

But all of this worked as long as I did the captchas at a reasonable rate. When I need to fill in 30 forms in half an hour, by the 10th form I'm getting extremely long captchas which sometimes fail even if the answer is correct, and I can't use the audio captcha.

I thought it might be related to web-gl, so I disabled it and tried again. Nope, same thing, couldn't even choose the audio captcha option because it said I could be sending automated requests. Tried disabling js, then both, neither worked. Tried another computer, got a few easy first captchas, then back to the hard ones.

I am not aware of how ReCAPTCHA does its validation behind the scenes, so even if it's not public knowledge, I'm asking if anyone has any estimations on how it works--and has attempted and succeeded at avoiding being temporarily blocked by ReCAPTCHA.

Just as extra info, using proxies and attempting this same thing on a normal browser in incognito mode returns the same results. Get a few easy quick challenges, then get destroyed by ReCAPTCHA with minute-long-challenges

If anyone has any tips, I'd appreciate it!

Comment: Actually, for testing purposes to test form with CAPTCHA you may need CAPTCHA bypass solution. E.g. you ay use a whitelisted email address, by entering which you can bypass CAPTCHA. Ask the developer to do that bypass.

Comment: Oh that sounds really useful, I'll try it, thanks!